How to handle incoming call notifications in React Native with Firebase when the app is in background or killed state?
Question:
I'm developing a social media app using React Native with Expo, and one of the main features is real-time audio and video calling. I'm using React Native WebRTC with a TURN server and WebSocket for signaling.
Everything works fine when the app is in the foreground (active state), and I'm able to navigate to the incoming call screen using WebSocket events. However, I'm facing issues when the app is in the background or killed state.
Problem:
When the app is in the background or killed, I can't rely on WebSocket events to notify the user of an incoming call. We decided to use Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to notify the user in these states, but we're struggling to display an incoming call notification (like WhatsApp or Messenger) that brings the app to the foreground and allows the user to answer the call.
What I've Tried:
Firebase Cloud Messaging:
I'm sending data payloads through FCM to handle the background/killed state.
The notification arrives, but I can't trigger the incoming call screen properly
react-native-callkeep:
I've integrated react-native-callkeep to display the native incoming call UI. It works when the app is in the foreground but not when it's backgrounded or killed.
I'm looking for guidance or a working example of how to:
Handle incoming call notifications using Firebase when the app is in the background or killed state.
Trigger the incoming call screen (or a similar UI) when the user receives the notification, allowing them to answer or reject the call.
Ensure this works reliably on both Android and iOS.
Any help or advice on how to properly implement this feature would be greatly appreciated!
Code Example:
Here’s a simplified version of my background message handler in React Native:
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import RNCallKeep from 'react-native-callkeep';

// FCM background handler
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);

  if (remoteMessage.data.type === 'incoming_call') {
    // Trying to display an incoming call UI
    RNCallKeep.displayIncomingCall(
      remoteMessage.data.callerId,
      remoteMessage.data.callerName,
      'audio' // Call type
    );
  }
});


Environment:
React Native: v0.72.10
Expo: v49.0.16
Firebase Cloud Messaging: v19.1.2
react-native-callkeep: v4.3.12
Platform: Android/iOS
Any suggestions or solutions are welcome. Thanks in advance!
